# "unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e" from 'aws ecr get-login'

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am trying to push a docker image to the aws ecr

When i  try to login to ect,

`aws ecr get-login`

It expands to something like this

> docker login -u AWS -p eyJwYXlsbXXXXXXVZIn0= -e none
>   https://88888888888.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

I got this error message:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'.
```

I have already upgraded the `awscli` to latest version 1.11.135

How can I remove this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aws ecs has updated their 'Push Commands' on ecs repositories lately. It is now

```
 aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2
```

You will also need to update the aws cli to the latest version

[image]